# How can I enable Cognito 'Email address or phone number' login using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create a new AWS Cognito user pool using Terraform, and currently have the following problem:

I've been trying to get **Email address or phone number** -> **Allow email addresses** (shown below in red) selected, instead of what is currently selected (**Username** -> **Also allow sign in with verified email address**)

[image: Screenshot of AWS Cognito]

The relevant section of my `main.tf` file looks like this:

```json
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "app_cognito_user_pool" {
  name = "app_cognito_user_pool"

  alias_attributes         = ["email"]
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]
  account_recovery_setting {
    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_email"
      priority = 1
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "app_cognito_user_pool_client" {
  name         = "app_cognito_user_pool_client"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.app_cognito_user_pool.id

  prevent_user_existence_errors = "ENABLED"
  supported_identity_providers  = ["COGNITO"]
}


resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "app_cognito_user_pool_domain" {
  domain       = "app"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.app_cognito_user_pool.id
}
```

No matter what I try, I always get *Username*, instead of *Email address or phone number* selected. I want the user pool **not** to use a username, but use an email address instead.

What Terraform argument(s) or value(s) am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Only set `username_attributes` - and not `alias_attributes` - to `["email"]`.**

---

Setting `alias_attributes` specifies the 'top part' i.e. *Also sign in with verified email address / phone number*.

It specifies the extra (alias) ways you can sign in, *in addition* to the username.

Setting [`username_attributes`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool#username_attributes) specifies the 'bottom part' i.e. *Allow email addresses / phone numbers / both email addresses and phone numbers ...*

It specifies what to use *instead* of the username.

---

Unset `alias_attributes` (as it conflicts with `username_attributes`) & then set `username_attributes' to one of the following:

1. `[“email”]` - *Allow email addresses*
2. `[“phone_number”]` - *Allow phone numbers*
3. `[“email”, “phone_number”]` - *Allow both email addresses and phone numbers (users can choose one*

In your case, you need to set `username_attributes` to `["email"]`.

---

This should work:

```json
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "app_cognito_user_pool" {
  name = "app_cognito_user_pool"

  username_attributes      = ["email"]
  auto_verified_attributes = ["email"]
  account_recovery_setting {
    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_email"
      priority = 1
    }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: That was it! I think I was misunderstanding **conflicts with** in the documentation, thinking it meant "being an alias of", instead of being a "different attribute that is exclusive with". Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @pragMATHiC More than welcome - `conflicts with` in the Terraform documentation means 'cannot use at the same time / only one of them should be used'. Enjoy using AWS!